# I want to generate PDF using page

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I want to generate PDFs in PHP. How can I do this?

I tried generating page PDF using MPDF but it can't generate the whole thing on page like extra images on pages and details etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: Have you seen http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html? I believe that's what Atlassian's Confluence tool uses to export pages as PDFs

Comment: Wow, I missed the PHP part. In that case, it definitely seems like a duplicate.